# Garbage collection issue with rabbitmq client

Tags: java, rabbitmq, out-of-memory

There is a java application in my project which uses rabbitmq library for message processing. Since few days the application is running out of memory.  After analysing the heap dump of the process we came to know that the one of the class in rabbitmq which processes the messages holding all the memory with byte[] of message body(ConsumerWorkService). The version of rabbitmq client used was 3.3.5
We change the rabbit mq client library to latest version and the application was running all fine. There was no out of memory issue.

I am not sure what was the root cause, is it rabbitmq library or the application. Do I need to investigate more with my application for this?

Comment: search rabbitmq changelog. If they say that memory leak was fixed, then you should be cool with new version. If they did not write it, and yet problem is not reproducible, you are good too, as there is no problem to fix